# como obtener pasarle la cantidad de un popup a la fila de la misma tabla con jquery

Tags: jquery

Hola tengo el siguiente problema estoy tratando de pasarle el valor de la cantidad a la misma fila que abre el popup pero a la tabla del carro. Lo que necesito tecnicamente es poder actualizar el valor que se ingresa en la cantidad del popup pero en la tabla tengo el siguiente código:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'tr.cart_item .tc-edit.tc-edit-normal', function() { 

let titulo = jQuery(this).parents('tr').children('td.product-name').text();
let foto = jQuery(this).parents('tr').children('td.tc-product-thumbnail').find('img').prop('src');
let precio = jQuery(this).parents('tr').children('td.product-price').find('bdi').text();
let cantidad = jQuery(this).parents('tr').children('td.product-quantity').find('input.qty').val();

let html = `
    <div class="tc-popup-prop-normal-foto">
        <img class="w-50" src="${foto}">
    </div>
    <div class="tc-popup-prop-normal-titulo">
        <h4>${titulo}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="tc-popup-prop-normal-precio">
        <p>Precio: ${precio}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tc-popup-prop-normal-button">
        <input id="cantidad" style="width:100px; text-align:center;" class="input-text-popup" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="10" value="${cantidad}">
        <button class="btn btn-warning text-white modificar">Modificar</button>
    </div>
`;

jQuery(document).on("click", '.modificar', function (){
    let cantidad_val = jQuery('#cantidad').val();
    jQuery('button.swal2-confirm.swal2-styled').click();
    jQuery('input.qty').attr('value', cantidad_val);
    jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').prop('disabled', false);
    jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').click();
})

Swal.fire({
    html: html,
    showClass: {
        popup: ''
    },
    hideClass: {
        popup: ''
    },
    confirmButtonText: 'Modificar',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cerrar',
    showCancelButton: false,
    imageWidth: 400,
    imageHeight: 200,
    imageAlt: 'Custom image',
})
```

})

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
necesito que el valor del popup se actualice acá en la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es el popup

Comment: actualmente me actualiza la cantidad de todas las filas necesito que sea en la fila que abre el poup gracias

Comment: les puedo compartir la url del sitio donde está el proyecto y agreguen un par de elementos al carro para que puedan ver el ejemplo en vivo acá les dejo el link: https://dev.kull.cl/appetite/carrito/

Comment: por favor ayuda alguien

Comment: Creo que el problema mas que técnico es de concepto, una vez actualizado el producto cuando abres el detalle en el carrito se debería actualizar. Una vez cierres el dialogo del detalle actualizas de nuevo la tabla con el nuevo valor, no es una buena practica el ir pasando los valores entre listados.

Comment: tienes un ejemplo con codigo no me importa si es buena o mala practica mi jefe me lo ha pedido asi y tengo que hacerlo es para salir del paso por favor

Comment: Simplemente crea una variable global y guarda el valor modificado por ejemplo y cuando se cierre el dialogo actualizas el campo en cuestión.